# Proof Verification: If $A\subseteq span(B)$ and $B\subseteq span(A)$ then $A=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Given vector space $V$ and subgroups $A,B\subseteq V$ I am supposed to prove the following true or false:

If $A\subseteq span(B)$ and $B\subseteq span(A)$ then $A=B$

Here is the proof I came up with:

$A\subseteq sp(B)\wedge B\subseteq sp(A)\Rightarrow A\subseteq sp(B)\subseteq B\subseteq sp(A)\subseteq A\Rightarrow A\subseteq B\subseteq A\Rightarrow A=B$

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you actually mean "subsets" instead of "subgroups"?

Comment: Would that change the answer?

Comment: That'd make your question logical, at least.

Comment: So I confirmed that it does indeed say subgroup.

Comment: Without any context, "group" or "subgroup" makes no sense when talking of vector spaces. And *where* does it say subgroup?

Comment: I thought this was odd too, but I found a very similar question from earlier that specifically says "subspace". It looks like for whatever reason, "subgroups" was not a mistake. I will ask the teacher today to clarify.

Comment: @DonAntonio Why does "group" or "subgroup" not make any sense?  A vector space is an abelian group under the addition operation.  So, using that interpretation, one would have the counterexample $\mathbb{Z},2\mathbb{Z}$ unequal subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$ with the same span.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Apparently you missed the "without any context" part. Just try to find *anywhere* you want some such question. I bet you'll hardly find one example here and there...if at all. At least it will be stressed "the subgroup of the abelian group of vectors" or something like that. Context is important here. BTW, I didn't understand what you meant with the last example you mention of $\;\Bbb Z,\,2\Bbb Z\;$ and etc...

Comment: @DonAntonio The question has now changed, but I took the question to mean that $A$ and $B$ must be subgroups of the additive group $V$ (forgetting the vector space structure).  The example is $V=\mathbb{R}$, $A=\mathbb{Z}$, and $B=2\mathbb{Z}$, which are subgroups of the additive group $V$, then the span of $A$ (or $B$) is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $A$.  But, since the question has changed, this approach isn't really what was meant anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false. In the real plane $\;\Bbb R^2_{\Bbb R}\;$ :

$$\left\{\binom 11\right\}\subset Sp\left\{\binom22\right\}\;\;\text{and also}\;\;\left\{\binom22\right\}\subset Sp\left\{\binom11\right\}\,,\,\,\text{yet}\;\;\left\{\binom 11\right\}\neq\left\{\binom 22\right\}$$

Comment: I think "subgroups" here means "subspaces".

Comment: @ArnaudD. Well, that'd change everything. Thanks, let's see what the OP says...

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is false because in general ${\rm Span}B\nsubseteq B$. A very simple counter example is

$$V=\mathbb{R}$$

$$A=\{1\},\:\:\:B=\{-1\}$$

It is easy to see that

$${\rm Span}A={\rm Span}B=\mathbb{R}$$

so indeed

$$A\subseteq{\rm Span}B,\:\:\:B\subseteq{\rm Span}A$$

But definitely $A\neq B$.

Comment: I think OP meant that $A,B$ are subspaces, in which case $span(B)=B$ is correct.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, but that'd make the question boringly trivial...

Comment: @DonAntonio Indeed, and moreover it looks like I may be wrong.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I agree with DonAntonio. In some languages group can be confused with set. Subspace is entirely different.

Answer (score 1):

If by "subgroups" you mean "subgroups of the additive group of $V$", i.e. non-empty subsets closed under addition but not necessary under scalar multiplication, then the claim is wrong. Indeed, $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$ are both subgroups of $\Bbb R$, and since $\Bbb R$ is a one-dimensional vector space, $\operatorname{span}(\Bbb Z)=\Bbb R=\operatorname{span}(\Bbb Q)$, but $\Bbb Z\neq \Bbb Q$.

Your mistake is exactly as eranreches pointed out : $\operatorname{span}(B)\subset B$ is false in general, and in fact it only holds if $B$ is a vector subspace, in which case you have equality.